# Exception: TODO: support lambda references in pyvsc's vsc.rangelist

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to run a python script [code_link](https://pastebin.com/g63x6GnE) which calls vsc.rangelist. I am getting the exception below. How to solve this issue?

```
Exception while processing constraint: 'ExprArraySubscriptModel' object has no attribute 'srcinfo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 62, in loop_c
self.loop_cnt_reg[i].inside(vsc.rangelist(compressed_gpr))
File "/home/az/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vsc/types.py", line 279, in __init__
to_expr(a)
File "/home/az/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vsc/types.py", line 334, in to_expr
raise Exception("TODO: support lambda references")
Exception: TODO: support lambda references

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 68, in <module>
obj = my_item()
File "/home/az/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vsc/rand_obj.py", line 82, in __init__
self.build_field_model(None)
File "/home/az/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vsc/rand_obj.py", line 211, in build_field_model
raise e
File "/home/az/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vsc/rand_obj.py", line 208, in build_field_model
fo.c(self)
File "test.py", line 62, in loop_c
self.loop_cnt_reg[i].inside(vsc.rangelist(compressed_gpr))
File "/home/az/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vsc/constraints.py", line 384, in __exit__
pop_constraint_scope()
File "/home/az/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/vsc/impl/ctor.py", line 135, in pop_constraint_scope
c.srcinfo = e.srcinfo
 AttributeError: 'ExprArraySubscriptModel' object has no attribute 'srcinfo'
```

Comment: the exception tells you that the library you are using, `vcs` does not support using lambdas, so try passing it proper functions. also, please do not link to external sites, paste your code in your question in code tags

Comment: please follow this useful guide for question asking.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example